# How do I target rows from a join table, that join with another table containing a specific value in any of its rows?

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have a employee in my employee table

```
[employee]

ID   Admin
1      1
2      1
3      0
```

and there is another table that highlights their roles

```
[employee_roles]

ID    Role
1     Admin
1     blah
1     blah
2     blah
3     blah
3     blah
```

I'd like to join the tables on the ID, and then if *any* of the employee_roles.Role are 'Admin', update the employee table to reflect that.

Or, alternatively, change the Admin column to a 0 otherwise.

It seems like a simple solution but I cannot produce the correct wording to find an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider this to not be optimal table design, because the answer to the question of whether a user be an admin is already completely contained within the `employee_roles` table.  So, I would just stop with the following query:

```
SELECT ID
FROM employee_roles
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Role = 'Admin' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

If you really wanted to do the update, then we can try joining the `employee` table to the above:

```
UPDATE employee e
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM employee_roles
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Role = 'Admin' THEN 1 END) > 0
) er
    ON e.ID = er.ID
SET Admin = 1;
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you. Will it work inversely if I change 'WHEN Role != 'Admin'' ?

Comment: Use `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Role = 'Admin' THEN 1 END) = 0` to detect non admins.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Very cool. Thanks for the information. Appreciate it.